# Parse Promise and Loop

Tags: loops, parse-platform, push-notification, promise

I'm having an issue with my background job that I created. Everything works fine in the first loop updates the object and saves it. Issue occurs when storing the object into an array and log out it's content I get:

```
I2015-01-26T16:00:17.861Z] Orders array is holding [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]

I2015-01-26T16:00:17.862Z] Order contains [object Object]

I2015-01-26T16:00:17.863Z] Order contains [object Object]

I2015-01-26T16:00:17.864Z] Order contains [object Object]

I2015-01-26T16:00:17.865Z] Order contains [object Object]

I2015-01-26T16:00:17.866Z] Order contains [object Object]

I2015-01-26T16:00:17.867Z] Order contains [object Object]

I2015-01-26T16:00:17.868Z] Order contains [object Object]
```

Then is it fails when trying to send out a push saying "get is not a method". I'm returning a parse promise using .when method but seems like I'm doing something wrong. If I use a for loop everything works fine, I get an array back and I'm able to send out a push notification. Only issue is that it only sends once then stops. The other users never receive a push. Please help.

```
var query = new Parse.Query(Order);
query.equalTo("payDate", payDate);
query.equalTo("complaintFiled", false);
query.find().then(function(orders){

    var promise = Parse.Promise.as();

    var objects = [];


    console.log(orders.length);

    _.each(orders, function(order) {

            console.log(order);

            counter += 1;
            order.set("sellerPaid", true);
            order.set("fullFilled", true);
            objects.push(order.save());

    });

    console.log("Paid " + counter + "sellers");
    console.log("Orders is holding " + orders.length);
    console.log("Orders array is holding "+ orders);    

    return Parse.Promise.when(objects);

}).then(function(orders){

    _.each(orders, function(order) {

        console.log("Order contains " + order);


            var seller     = order.get("seller");
            var amountOwed = order.get("amountOwed");
            var message    = "A payment was made to your account in the amount of $" + amountOwed + " .";

            var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
            query.equalTo("user", seller);

             Parse.Push.send({
                where: query,
                data:{
                    alert: message,
                    badge: "Increment",
                    title: "Payment Made!"
                }
            }, {
                success: function(){

                    console.log("Success");
                },
                error: function(error) {


                   response.error(errMsg);

                }
          });
    });

}).then(function(){


    status.success("Completed background job");


}, function(error){


    status.error(error);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the answer [here](https://parse.com/questions/parsepromisewhen-doesnt-work) :

> The callback for when gets one argument for each Promise.

So unlike say Bluebird, the results are automatically spread, not delivered in an array.

Try :

```js
    ...
    return Parse.Promise.when(objects);
}).then(function() {//<<< no formal vars
    _.each(arguments, function(order) {//<<< `arguments`, not `orders`
    ...
```

`_.each()` should accept `arguments`. If not just do the standard `Array.prototype.slice.apply(arguments)` trick.